# how to toggle a filter so that it selects only one item at a time?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I have 2 charts. A bar chart and a donut chart (with 3 categories ['A','B','C']). 
When I click on a segment of the donut, then I toggle that element's membership in the filter.

e.g. If ['A','B','C'] are selected, and I click on 'A', then I am left with ['B','C']. If I click again on 'A', then I am returned to the full set.

Is it possible to change this behaviour, so that a click, 'de-selects' everything that is not 'A'. So when I click on 'A', I get 'A', and when I click on 'B', I get 'B' etc.

This [example](https://becomingadatascientist.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/create-rich-interactive-visualisations/) achieves this for the rowChart in line 174, but I neither understand the implementation, nor can I reproduce this in my own work.

The relevant code is pasted here:

```js
rowChart.width(340)
        .height(850)
        .dimension(cityDimension)
        .group(cityGroup)
        .renderLabel(true)
        .colors(["#a60000","#ff0000", "#ff4040","#ff7373","#67e667","#39e639","#00cc00"])
        .colorDomain([0, 0])
        .renderlet(function (chart) { // <-this bit onwards does the magic (I think)
            bubbleChart.filter(chart.filter());
        })
        .on("filtered", function (chart) {
            dc.events.trigger(function () {
                bubbleChart.filter(chart.filter());
            });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In d3 if you need to filter some data out of a bigger dataset you could do like so:

```
var filter = dataset.filter(function (d) { retrurn d.ValueToFilter == "FilterToApply"; });
```

For example, if you have a fruit dataset, and you just want orange, you do something like so:

```
var filter = dataset.filter(function (d) { return d.fruit == "orange"; })
```

This will return only values that have the `"orange"` property in `d.fruit`